# Facebook XFBML 'Like' Button won't make individual like buttons for each of my pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, xfbml

I'm a rather beginning programmer trying to get the XFBML 'Like' button to work on my site correctly... I chose the XFBML so I wouldn't have to manually type in the URL for each button- I use a lot of templates and want to be able to update everything quickly and easily.

But about half my pages seem to share a like button- and strangely, the other half each have their own individual like buttons, even pages that use the same template as the first set.  How do I fix this?  I've seen some stuff for blogs about automatically generating different like buttons, but I'm not sure it'll work because this a regular old site and every page is a different URL.  I've searched all over the place online and I haven't seen anyone else with this problem.  The site is at www.millerandcampbell.com if that helps.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the future, plase use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to debug problems like this.

It [clearly shows](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.millerandcampbell.com/rental.html) that f.e. for the page `http://www.millerandcampbell.com/rental.html` you have given your base address `http://www.millerandcampbell.com` as value for `og:url` – and of course the like button respects that value, and therefor likes the latter URL.

If you don’t want that – then set `og:url` to the *actual* address of your sub-pages.

Comment: Sorry, I did look over Facebooks support stuff several times and couldn't figure out my problem.  I also used the Linter and I know the base address is entered for the og:url (I tried to leave it blank, but the linter didn't like that).  As I stated above, I'm hoping to not have to go through to each of my individual pages and manually put in the address under og:url.  Is there a way to make it automatically connect to the page it's on and only that page?  And why does it still work the way I want it to on some of my pages when every single one has the same base address listed under og:url?